# Android/Facebook - invalid_key on device, but not on emulator

Tags: android, facebook

I obtained a key for my Android/Facebook app using the following:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I gave this to Facebook and the app now works perfectly within the emulator, both with and without the Facebook app installed. However, when I packaged the app and put it on my phone (HTC Desire), I get the invalid_key error when authenticating. Could anyone shed any light on why this is happening? Do I need to use a different key?

Comment: Create an own key with keytool for packaging. As the name says, the debug key is only for debugging and is not associated with the real vendor, company and so on.

Comment: You need to create an own keystore with your own key in it and use it for packaging the app.

Comment: So use the keystore I've been using for packaging, with the same command as above?

Comment: `keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048` from http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

Comment: Can I not just use the same key I've been using? This appears to generate a new one.

Comment: yeah, you don't need a new key, you need to get the code that Facebook wants generated from the key you currently use to compile your app (not the debug one)

Comment: to be clear... there is a debug key (that is what you're currently using) that will NOT work with a packaged apk.  So, if you have never generated a key to export your app, you will have to do that at least once.. you can then always use that key for your apk exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes... you need to use the same key you use for actually compiling the app (the one that you use in the export process) otherwise it mismatches.

It's a (small) PITA, you need to keep them both on hand and swap them out, so that when you're debugging you're using one and when you actually compile your apk you use the other.

I've gotten into the habit of just quickly compiling my apk and using adb to install/uninstall it onto my attached device, so, I don't bother with the debug version at all... but if you prefer you can just keep swapping them out on the Facebook App editor page.

Comment: So should I use the above command, but rather than the debug keystore, swap in the keystore for Android (the one used in Eclipse)?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel you don't need a key to compile the code, only for packaging/export.

Comment: @Joel, that's correct... make sure you have the alias right, cause the key generator won't warn you that it's wrong and will give you a bogus key instead!

Comment: @Stephan, I'm not sure what you mean... you need a key to package an apk, right? And Facebook needs that key to verify that your app is the app it says it is.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel thats right. Just wanted to clarify that compiling and packaging are two different steps.

Comment: By alias do you mean the password?

Comment: when you set up a key, you set up an alias (with its own password)... so, you have the initial password, and then an alias with its password.  It's all part of the same keystore.

Comment: When you export your app, you'll be asked for the keystore and its password, and then on the next dialog screen you have to select an alias (that it pulls from the cert) and enter THAT password as well.