# Android facebook post works on emulator but not on device - How do I get the right key Hash?

Tags: android, facebook, hash, keystore

I am working on an android app that among other things also posts a string message in user's wall. The app works fine on the emulator posting the message on my on wall every time. But whenever I try to work it from a device it just doesn't post anything. From debugging so far I see that the authentication fails on the device, while it succeeds on emulator.

From my research I found this -> [Android/Facebook - invalid_key on device, but not on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957714/android-facebook-invalid-key-on-device-but-not-on-emulator)

So as far as I understand I need another key for my app to be able to run on a real device. Is there someone who can provide some simple, step by step instructions on how to retrieve this key using the cmd? I tried many things based on that topic's answer and I am currently at a loss..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a valid key to have create a valid keystore. This is created when you follow the "export your application process". Then you have to use this 'public' keystore in order to generate the required hash for the Facebook.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! The fact is that I do not have today an android device to test (I will inform you as soon as I test it of course).
What I tried, was to sign my app in the way that it is shown in this tutorial -> http://www.devx.com/wireless/article/39972/1954

Then I created the hash key for the keystore that I signed my app in 
with-> "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\George.android\keystorname.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e"
Was that what you meant? Should I change the "androiddebugkey" in the command above to something else?

Comment: Nop the alias is just a name. The important is to use the public keystore like you did now.

Comment: So you think it should work? (I tried to change the name and it gave the same key, so you must be right). I'll inform you as soon as I test it on device. Thank you again!

Comment: it does not work! I just got the key I produced and inserted it in the "Android Key Hash:" field for my app in the https://developers.facebook.com/ site. In the emulator it is still working.. Should I do anything more than that?